# Sorting with special characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with sorting a select from MySQL. 
I have some names with starts with "A", "Á", "Z" and "Ž" to show a few. The strange thing is, that "A" and "Á" are sorted like the same letter instead of the separate letters. 
Which means that it may come out like this:

- Aak
- Adv
- Ága
- Agg
- Ahm

I know Á is a subletter to A, but I want it to be grouped, so all A's come first and then the Á.
The collation on the field is utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
If Á is taken for the same letter as A, then the sort is okay, as it looks at the next letter and so on. But I want Á to be separated from A, so it will sort like this instead:

- Aak
- Adv
- Agg
- Ahm
- Ága

Comment: Which server version?

Comment: MySQL is at 5.7. Can't remember minor, if needed I have to check

Comment: But you need it to be UTF?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by UTF, as it already is in UTF8MB4.
I'll update the question, as it is easiere to make the layout

Comment: I mean that it works with `latin1`: `order by convert(word using latin1) collate latin1_general_ci;` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8yZu6eWWpoesk8yBWruPWM/0

Comment: Well not exactly, as it seems that it put all the special characters last, which I don't want either.

Comment: It sorts A A A Á Á B C

Comment: Okay, maybe I was a bit to fast. Á is then sorted after A but before B, which is good. But Š and Ž is not sorted after S nor Z, but last overall. I updated your example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8yZu6eWWpoesk8yBWruPWM/1

Comment: You can try out other latin character sets/collations, like `latin2_czech_cs`, which languages do you need to support?

Comment: Just tried to change the collation on a test field to latin1. It can't show all needed characters and show a ? instead. I need to support Danish/Norwegian, Swedish, Polish, Slovenian and German.

Answer (score 0):

The following 3 collations for `UTF8MB4` character set look promising, that is, `utf8mb4_icelandic_ci`, `utf8mb4_is_0900_ai_ci`, and `utf8mb4_is_0900_as_cs`. The result using @Paul Spiegel's example is:

```
word
====
Ab
Ac
Ae
Ád
Áf
Ba
Ca
Št
Zo
Žv
```

[db-fiddle code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8yZu6eWWpoesk8yBWruPWM/2)

I identified them by checking through the available collations using `PROCEDURE`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Try_Collation`()
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE c_collation varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

-- read available collations for utf8mb4
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT COLLATION_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS
    WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME='utf8mb4';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

OPEN table_cursor;

    Loop_label: LOOP -- test individual collations by loop

    -- read one collation to table_cursor
    FETCH table_cursor INTO c_collation;

    IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE Loop_label;
    END IF;
    
    -- save the ordered table to a temp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (
        `word` varchar(50)
        );

    SET @s=CONCAT(
        "INSERT INTO temp_table ",
        "(select word from test ",
        "order by convert(word using utf8mb4) ",
        "collate ",c_collation,");");
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    -- set some filtering rules for checking orders
    IF (select word from temp_table limit 2,1)='Ád' THEN
        ITERATE Loop_label; -- skip to next loop iteration
    END IF;
    IF (select word from temp_table limit 5,1)='Zo' THEN
        ITERATE Loop_label; -- skip to next loop iteration
    END IF;
    
    SELECT c_collation; -- print out current collation
    SELECT * FROM temp_table; -- print out ordered table

    END LOOP Loop_label;

CLOSE table_cursor;

END;

CALL Try_Collation();
```

[Code link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cd8b3992e0736702a9ab74f7137cf96)